# Javascript what's wrong with this dummy link?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Base on a dummy input code here at stackoverflow, I'm trying to make a dummy link code, set the link some external webpage, then automatically click this link to redirect to that external page. Thus, after redirection, I can use "document.referrer", without getting empty result. (I just learned,"document.referrer" do need clicking a link. )
Will it work? at least worth a try.
But the following code(bookmarklet) turned out nothing... no redirection at all.

```js
javascript:var dummy = document.createElement("a");  document.body.appendChild(dummy);  dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");   
dummy.setAttribute("href", "http://new.cloudfile.co/transfer");
$( document ).ready(function() { $(".dummy_id").click();});  
var tmp=document.referrer;
alert(tmp);
```

Comment: You are using $ symbol, which is not javascript inbuilt feautre. And please follow guideline on how to post the code

Comment: @user3045179 Thanks for your help. That Jquery code is the only way I could learn to do an automatic clicking. Any alternative?  And please tell me what's wrong with my posting code.... is it "javascript:"?  that should be included in a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three (3) issues:

1. Your use of `$` here looks like jQuery, but you haven't loaded jQuery
2. You're setting an ID but you're searching for a class... Replace `$(".dummy_id").click();` with `document.getElementById('dummy_id').click();`
3. You don't need a `DOMContentLoaded` (i.e., `$.ready`) handler for this kind of bookmarklet

Comment: Thank you, sir, with "document.getElementById('dummy_id').click();", the code works fine.